# chunk a file with fuse

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, fuse

If we have a large file that needs to be stored on multiple storage media with limited space, it there a fuse-based solution that works at the file level?

To give a concrete example, let's say we have a large file which is 2TB. And we have four hard disks with 500GB capacity each mounted at 4 different dirs. Obviously we need to split the large file into the four dirs because each can hold 500GB at most.

One way to split the large file is to create a 2TB logical volume on top of 500GB physical volume using lvm. But this would require us to work at the block level and use loop-back devices, which may not always be available.

I've read about unionfs and chunkfs, but it doesn't seem any works in this case. unionfs only aggregates files at the dir level. chunkfs provides a chunked view of the large file, but doesn't split the write operation across different dirs.

Comment: Now I'm curious: What environment are you in where FUSE would be always available, but loopback devices may not?

Comment: @dirkt When you are in a container, or when you don't have root.